# Call external (non-local, not in www) CSS files in Shiny

Tags: css, shiny

I would like to use CSS files not hosted on my Shiny server. Essentially, I'm at a university and would like to reference standard styles (and be seen to be using standard styles) without having to harvest all their styles and copy it to my server any time they update.

`tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "custom.css")` work great for custom.css within www, but I can't seem to reference an outside server.

I've also tried `@import url('www.masterserver.edu/global.css')` within my custom.css file to no avail.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `tags$head(tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "http://www.masterserver.edu/global.css"))` should do the trick, just make sure to put the `http://`.

Comment: That worked – thanks!